# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near '-sporocilo us, uporabnik u WHERE ( 's%' LIKE
u.uuser) AND (s.SID = us.SID) AND (' at line 2
```

this is the error i get ...

SQL:

```
SELECT us.ussender, s.ssubject, s.scontent, us.ustimesend, us.usstatus,
FROM sporocilo s, uporabnik-sporocilo us , uporabnik u
WHERE ($user LIKE u.uuser) AND (s.SID = us.SID) AND (us.usreciever LIKE u.uuser),
ORDER BY us.ustimesend ASC;
```

Database: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/20224/20140415-ls6n-41kb

Comment: Are you trying to substract tables? ;-P `uporabnik-sporocilo`

Comment: It the name of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column identifiers are going to contain dashes you *must* wrap them in ticks. Otherwise MySQL assumes you are performing a subtraction operation.

```
SELECT us.ussender, s.ssubject, s.scontent, us.ustimesend, us.usstatus, 
FROM sporocilo s, `uporabnik-sporocilo` us , uporabnik u 
WHERE ($user LIKE u.uuser) AND (s.SID = us.SID) AND (us.usreciever LIKE u.uuser), 
ORDER BY us.ustimesend ASC;
```

Comment: @user2603949 Also, as a side note, please start using explicit joins, implicit ones are deprecated. You should also know that the `LIKE`s that you are using are basically and `=` operator since you are not using any wildcards (`'%'`)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is missing quotes, here:

```
WHERE ($user LIKE u.uuser) AND (s.SID = us.SID) AND (us.usreciever LIKE u.uuser),
```

plus the comma at the end of that line.

There are other problems with your query, but that is beyond the scope of your question.